# How is mouse stutter related to CPU clock speed?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, mouse, gaming

This might sound really weird but it is true.
When I play CS:GO with my CPU running at 3.3GHz I get very slight mouse stuttering/glitching occasionally. 
Using all the same in-game setting, I reboot the PC and access the BIOS to change the clock speed to 3.7GHz (auto overclocking, changes all the setting automatically).
Going back I game everything works smooth with no mouse stuttering or glitching.

I am wondering why am I getting this issue (stutter/glitching) and **how is it possible that different CPU clock speeds would remedy the issue or cause it.**

#### Background information:

- **CPU** - i7 950 3.07GHz (stock)
- **Motherboard** - Asus Rampage 3 Formula
- **Mouse** - Corsair M60 (newest firmware and drivers)
- **OS** - Windows 8.1 Pro x64
- **Game** - CS:GO ~250FPS

Answer (score 0):

The different CPU clock speeds might be remedy the issue or cause of it.

Each I/O device has an operating frequency Associated with it. So here after overclocking your CPU the frequency of your CPU might be exactly matching (means running parallely not with the same frequency), Instead of Overclocking your CPU you can check by changing the operating frequency of your Mouse your mouse can operate at the frequency of 1000Hz/500Hz/250Hz/125Hz (1ms/2ms/4ms/8ms) selectable response time. [source](http://www.corsair.com/en/vengeance-m60-performance-fps-laser-gaming-mouse)